# How to Group the Borough column by each the 5 boroughs in NYC, and taking average of the total population in each Borough

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

[image]

I need to create box plot which has the average population of each borough. I have the population of each of the zip codes in each of the 5 boroughs. How can I get to my preferred result? Open the link to see my dataframe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby):

`df.groupby('Borough')['Population'].sum()`

If you want by `Borough` and `Zip_codes`:

`df.groupby(['Borough', 'Zip_codes')['Population'].sum()`